# What "Synthetic" means in xev output?

Tags: xorg, keyboard

If to run xev and press Alt, it generates following event among others:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0xa600001,
    root 0x5bc, subw 0x0, time 823983987, (672,346), root:(672,411),
    state 0x0, keycode 64 (keysym 0xffe9, Alt_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

What exactly "Synthetic" means in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `synthetic` is `YES` instead of `NO`, it means that the event is a "fake" one, generated by another X11 client with [`XSendEvent(3)`](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man3/XSendEvent.3.html), not by the server.

Many programs (e.g. `xterm`, `firefox`) ignore synthetic events (except for ClientMessage events). This is more of a feel-good measure than any kind of real security, because an X11 client can easily generate key and mouse events via the XTest extension (present and enabled by default).